# gethostname() function missing in openMPI

Tags: mpi

I had to replace mpich2 with OpenMPI due to dependency of OpenFOAM on OpenMPI.

Earlier (when using mpich2) in my code I was using gethostname() function to get the name of the machine for debugging purpose. However this function does not seem to be a standard MPI function, and is not working anymore with OpenMPI libraries. Is there any other function for getting the host name in OpenMPI, or MPI standard? I am using mpicc for compiling and mpirun for running the code.

Thanks,

Sourabh

Comment: `gethostname` is not a standard MPI function.  Are you confusing it with `MPI_Get_processor_name` which is ?

Comment: Actually gethostname() used to work earlier, after installing OpenMPI it stopped working. I just checked MPI_Get_processor_name() is working, Thanks.

Comment: The prototype of `gethostname()` is in `unistd.h`. How exactly is it not working with Open MPI?

Comment: I am not sure how! I had not included `unistd.h` but `gethostname()` was working when I was including only `mpi.h` and `stdio.h`
The only explanation I have is that `gethostname()` might be defined inside some library in `mpich2`'s `mpi.h`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gethostname()` is defined in `unistd.h` that was included by `mpi.h`, in the previous version. That's not a feature you should rely on, since you should always explicitly include the files which define the symbols you use. Clearly you were relying on it without realizing.

However if your MPI code is supposed to run on POSIX systems only, its safe to add

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

`gethostname()` is POSIX2001.1 standard.

However the MPI portable solution is `MPI_Get_processor_name()` as shown in the comment by **High Performance Mark**