# MPI error - channel initialization failed

Tags: python, fortran, mpi

I am running an easy Fortran 90 program (Hello world) with MPI. 
The compilation works fine, if I run `./a.out` I get the message, but as soon as I run

```
$mpiexec -n 1 exec ./a.out
```

I get two errors:

> channel initialization failed

and

> gethostbyname failed

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRNi2.png). If I run a similar Python script what I get is [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jr3I1.png).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MPICH2 gethostbyname failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23112515/mpich2-gethostbyname-failed)

Comment: I saw that and I don't think it's the case because I can ssh into 127.0.0.1.
In my etc/hosts I see

127.0.0.1 localhost. 

LITERALLY localhost and not MY localhost (albertobottopoala). I wanted to try to change it but I am afraid of the damages I could make, It says expressly not to change it...

Comment: For the Python error, use `mpiexec -n 1 python hello_world.py` instead of `mpiexec -n 1 hello_world.py`.

Comment: Same output....

Comment: Any luck with this, I am having similar issues and would like to know what is the root of this problem, how I may go about solving it.