# How to get <rank,hostname> pair in the specified hostfile in MPI

Tags: mpi

When running MPI program, we use command
`mpiexec -hostfile ./conf/machines <my_mpi_program>`

My hostfile `./conf/machines`

```
192.168.1.54
192.168.1.55
192.168.1.56
192.168.1.57
```

And When executing MPI program, i got my processor rank by `MPI_Comm_rank`.
My question is how to get `<rank, hostname>` pair of each rank ?
The `hostname` should be the same with the hostfile i spcecified, and i just want to use ipaddress as the hostname in hostfile.

I tried to use `MPI_Get_processor_name` but it returned the name of my host `teaker-4` , not the name in the specified hostfile.

And also, `teaker-4` is `127.0.0.1`, and I cannot modify `/etc/hosts`

Comment: The answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689707/how-to-know-the-which-core-a-process-is-running-on-in-mpi may assist you.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark , the link tells which CPU core the MPI process is running on, I want to know which machine the given rank(get by MPI_Comm_rank) is running on, it's not the same thing. anyway,  thanks a lot. :D

Comment: @zorksylar Just to clarify, you want to programatically extract the specific host ip inside the MPI process? Also I believe it is `--hostfile`. Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174901/gethostname-function-missing-in-openmpi

Comment: @Karl thanks for your link. But `MPI_Get_processor_name` will return the hostname in the `/etc/hosts` file. What i want to do is to get the `<rank, hostname>` pair , and the `hostname` is in the `conf/machines` file, not in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: @zorksylar could you just disseminate the machines file to the children and lookup there. or call `gethostbyname` or something similar along that line of reasoning to extract the ip address? [get ip address of host programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212528/get-the-ip-address-of-the-machine)

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is what you wanted, albiet tardy:

I use this approach within my mpi programs:

.. usual mpi fortran setup use.. decalare.. including:

use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding

use mpi

implicit none

interface

function gethostid() BIND(C)

use iso_c_binding

integer (C_INT) :: gethostid

end function gethostid

end interface

.. then the usual more declarations and assignments until mpi begins ..

!Adapting part of the cpu process rank-to-gpu-id mapping code from the PGI OpenACC with MPI Tutorial Version 2017 #4...

call MPI_INIT(ierr2)

! get the hostids so we can determine which mpi processes are on each node

hostid=gethostid()

I should also point out (thanks Gilles for the prompt) that gethostid() returns the ip address of the host, not the hostname, but in every HPC environment I have used there has been a way of acquiring the hostname:ip address mapping, sometimes in large HPC environments this involves knowing which cluster you are running your job in and the netmask for that cluster, and/or asking a sysadmin nicely.  E.g. for my home beowulf cluster, the head node's ip address is 192.168.178.57  according to ipconfig, and when I print the hostname integer for that node as above in z10 ('zoned' hex) format I get C0A8B339, which matches. I also know the real hostname that matches that IP address, in this case because I made the /etc/hosts file myself, but in larger systems where you are not sysadmin you can usually find the hostname ip mapping other ways.

.. and then you can map the process:hostname in your program and go from there.

I note of caution: you are relying on interoperating with a provided c function that you did not write yourself, and I have used at least one large HPC environment where the zoned hexadecimals were cyclicly permuted. Some 'endian' slackness?

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot get what was written in the hostfile on the compute ranks.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).